# Line not intersecting circle, maximum value of expression involving radius

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles

If line $y+x=2$ do not intersect any member of circles $x^2 + y^2 -ax = 0$ at two distinct points where a is parameter, then maximum value of  $|a + 4|$.

My try:
Since the line does not intersect the circle at 2 distinct points therefore the distance of line from center of circle is greater than or equal to the radius of the circle

> Circle is $x^2 + y^2 -ax = 0$ therefore its radius is $a$ and center is $(a, 0)$
>
> Distance of line $x^2 + y^2 -ax = 0$ from center of circle is given by $\frac{|a - 2|}{\sqrt2}$
>
> Therefore we get the inequality $$\frac{|a - 2|}{\sqrt2} \ge a$$

But I can't find a way to solve it further to obtain the maximum value of |a + 4|

Comment: Try to find values of $a$ such that line and circle are tangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use substitution to solve the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 - ax = 0 \\
y + x = 2
\end{cases}
&\implies x^2 + (2 - x)^2 - ax = 0 \\
&\implies x^2 + (4 - 4x + x^2) - ax = 0 \\
&\implies 2x^2 + (-a - 4)x + 4 = 0 \\
\end{align*}
But since there is at most one intersection point, we know that this equation must have at most one solution so that the discriminant of the LHS is either negative or zero:
\begin{align*}
(-a - 4)^2 - 4(2)(4) &\leq 0 \\
(-(a + 4))^2 - 32 &\leq 0 \\
(a + 4)^2 &\leq 32 \\
\sqrt{(a + 4)^2} &\leq \sqrt{32} \\
|a + 4| &\leq 4\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Was the expression I got difficult to solve ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you came up with that expression. For one thing, the circle's centre is actually at $(\frac{a}{2}, 0)$ and its radius is actually $\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: oh yes! I made this mistake yet another time....